# How do I correctly use toLower in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I've recently started to learn Haskell and wanted to convert something to lowercase. I looked up the function "toLower", but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Prelude> import Data.Text
Prelude Data.Text> toLower "JhELlo"

<interactive>:2:9: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Text' with actual type `[Char]'
    * In the first argument of `toLower', namely `"JhELlo"'
      In the expression: toLower "JhELlo"
      In an equation for `it': it = toLower "JhELlo"
Prelude Data.Text> toLower 'JhELlo'

<interactive>:3:9: error:
    * Syntax error on 'JhELlo'
      Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell or TemplateHaskellQuotes
    * In the Template Haskell quotation 'JhELlo'
Prelude Data.Text>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It doesn't work, because the version you tried to use operates on `Text`, and not `String`. Those are two distinct types. You have two options at this point:

1) Use `toLower` from `Data.Char`; this one operates on a single character, and you can map it over your string:

```
map toLower "JhELlo"
```

2) Convert you string to `Data.Text` (and optionally back again):

```
unpack . toLower . pack $ "JhELlo"
```

There are actually [other versions of `toLower`](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=toLower) around; the one in `Data.Sequences` seems to be polymorphic (so should work on both), but it might require pulling in the `mono-traversable` package as a dependency.

Comment: And if you have a choice, `Data.Text.toLower` should be preferred to `Data.Char.toLower`, because its behavior is more correct on international texts. For example, `Data.Text.toLower "İ" = "i\775"` (two output codepoints!) whereas `Data.Char.toLower "İ" = "i"` is just an approximation.

Comment: What is "\755"?

Comment: I see, "\755" is a unicode character by its decimal codepoint.